# What are the odds of having all 4 of your children (no multiples) on the same day of the week?

Tags: probability

(retrying my phrasing)

What are the odds of having 4 (and only 4) naturally conceived, naturally birthed, singleton children (with the same and only mate) on a given day of the week (ie, Wednesday)?

Equations with explanations appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Another question you might like to consider is "what is the probability of four out of four kids all being born on the same day of the week?". This might be more relevant if you would consider it equally amazing if the kids were all born on a Thursday, or all born on a Friday.

Comment: Doctors do C-section Wednesday mornings, hit the links in the afternoon (real story is that birth day of week is not equal across days of week, and may not be independent for same doctor or hospital across multiple kids). Also, do you really want to know probability of all kids being born on Wednesday, or do you want to know probability that all kids are born on the same day of the week? Also, if you go "hunting" after the fact for unlikely events or records, it's easy to find them - that's a form of massive simultaneity bias.

Comment: If day of week that kids are born on is really independent (across your kids) and identically distributed with probability 1/7 (none of which are likely true), then the probability that all 4 kids are born on Wed. is $(1/7)^4$, which can be viewed as the probability of 4 successes in a Binomial Distribution with 4 trials, each of which has probability 1/7 of success, defined as "kid born on Wednesday".

Comment: Given the P.S., the first kid will be born on some day of the week.  Then the probability that all 3 remaining kids are born on that same day of the week is $(1/7)^3$, which is 7 times more likely than that they all are born on Wednesday. If you have trouble wrapping your head around that, just think what would happen if there were a total of 2 kids: the first kid is born on some day of the week, and there is a 1/7 probability that the 2nd kid will be born on that same day of the week, whatever it happens to be.

Comment: Well, you didn't have 8 kids, you had 4 kids, so calculations for 8 kids don't enter into the calculations.  If you want to calculate the probability that with 8 kids, exactly 4 will be born on some day, or as a different question, the first 4 will be born on the same day and none of the remaining 4 on that day, or another question at least 4 are born on the same day of the week,, or any number of other questions, those would be different calculations.

Comment: One important point, is that you have picked out a pattern as a coincidence, and then asked for the odds of that particular pattern, but you should really ask what are the odds of any identifiable pattern, e.g., all born on the same day, or on consecutive days, or on days beginning with a T or an S, or in the same month, or on the same day of the month, or in consecutive months, or or or.  The odds of some kind of coincidence are actually quite high.

Comment: @Kelvin , your most recent comment is what I was trying to get at in the last sentence of my 1st comment.  As for quadruplets, that blows the independence assumption across kids out of the water. Of course, if you want to game the system, you can fly in a plane near the international dateline, and no matter what time of day, by going to one side or the other, you have a choice of 2 days of the week.

Comment: I'm surprised this was closed, since there are some reasonably interesting statistical questions here (e.g., post-hoc hypothesizing, choosing a stopping rule). The original question was pretty light-hearted, but that's not necessarily a bad thing…